# Is RavenDB just a frontend for Access?

Tags: ms-access, ravendb, jet

I've started using Raven for my last project. When my boss learned about it, he mentioned it's based on Access and he had very bad experience with multiple users and Access. Now I have to either switch or prove to him he is wrong.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I seriously doubt it's based on or a layer over Access.  RavenDB is a document database, which is fundamentally different than a SQL database like Access.

Comment: It is OpenSource, you can check for yourself. http://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/

Comment: @Nacereddine yeah, and then change the engine if I don't like it ....

Comment: @Eric J. the thing is it uses a Jet engine to write those documents to disk

Comment: But not the same jet engine that Access uses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it isn't. The confusion is because RavenDB can use ESENT for data storage and ESENT used to be called Jet Blue. It was called Jet Blue because it was originally developed to replace the Jet Red engine which was/is used in Access. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine#History) entry is quite accurate about the history and differences.

Comment: It's worth saying that ESENT is the ISAM database that is also used by Exchange and by the Windows Active Directory and various Windows components.

Answer (score 3):

Laurion's answer is correct, but I also wanted to point out that in Raven you can swap out the ESENT storage engine for another that Oren developed called Munin.

From [Ayende's blog post about Munin](http://ayende.com/blog/4686/raven-munin).

> Raven.Munin is the actual implementation of a low level managed storage for RavenDB. I split it out of the RavenDB project because I intend to make use of it in additional projects.
>
> At its core, Munin provides high performance transactional, non relational, data store written completely in managed code. The main point in writing it was to support the managed storage in RavenDB, but it is going to be used for Raven MQ as well, and probably a bunch of other stuff as well. I’ll post about Raven MQ in the future, so don’t bother asking about it.
>
> Munin is a low level api, not something that you are likely to use directly. And it was explicitly modeled to give me an interface similar in capability to what Esent gives me, but in purely managed code.